# Overlaping graphics not visible in featureLayer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, overlapping-features, feature-dataset

I have constructed a featureCollection from JSON and the feature collection has 44 features.

I have given this feature collection as input to the Featurelayer which is showing only 32 graphics objects of the featurecollection.

I found out that overlapping features are not rendered at all in the feature layer.

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your .json file somewhere (dropbox or some other free hosting service) so we can reproduce this? That would be the easiest and fastest way to see if this is a bug and/or if there is a workaround.

Comment: My bad "esriFieldTypeOID"(Treating as primary key) had duplicate values which where overlapping so even though I was able to see those records in feature collection it was not seen as geometry for the feature layer. I changes one one of the record then geometries where overlapping fine .Thanks for the comments @Derek Swingley.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. You should post that as answer and then mark your post as the answer to this question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var featureCollection = {
                                layerDefinition: {
                                    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
                                    "fields": [
                                   {
                                       "name": "ID",
                                       "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",  //$Expects to be unique
                                       "alias": "ID"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "name": "miles",
                                       "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
                                       "alias": "miles"
                                   }
                                ]
                                },
                                featureSet: fs
                            };

                            var FeatureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
                                mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
                                infoTemplate: template,
                                outFields: ['ID', 'miles']
                            });
```

when we give feature collection as input to the Featurelayer it was treating id as field with unique value and and expects to be of type esriFieldTypeOID when it may be of any other type.The feature collection shows all duplicates value also but when we give feature collection as input to Featurelayer it takes only one features with duplicate value and drops other features.